# If $f$ is a monotonically decreasing smooth function with domain $[0, \infty]$ and range $[0, 1]$ is it necessarily exponential?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am looking for a characterisation of smooth, monotone functions with infinite domain (in real numbers) and bounded range.

Clearly $e^{-x}$ works. Will functions satisfying this criteria be always exponential in nature?

Comment: No you can also have functions like $\arctan$ (suitably rescaled)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No: $$f(x)=\frac1{x+1}$$ is one of many other examples.  Take the reciprocal of any smooth function $g(x)$ with $g(0)=1$ which increases towards $+ \infty$ for more; in your example $g(x)=e^x$ while in mine $g(x)=x+1$